# UITableView add Button design decision

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm writing a Musicplayer and want to be able to use playlists. Since this is a view I segue to, I'm wandering, where best to put the Add Button.

Since I need 3 Buttons (Back -in the pictures Playlists-, Add and Start) in total, I was thinking about adding an extra Row at the end of the table to add but couldn't find if anyone ever used it this way.

[image: extra row]

The normal way would be to add a '+' in the top right of the navigation bar. But then I don't know where to place the Play Button.

[image: normal +]

The iPhone Music App places an extra row at the top for extra Buttons.

[image: iPhone Music]

But since I only need 1 more Button I'm looking for an alternative.

Are the any reasons not to place the add button as a row in the tableview? Or where is the best place to do this?

Thanks a lot!

//EDIT: added images

Comment: A screenshot or two would be really helpful here. Almost everyone is used to find the + button on the top far right as far as iOS goes. Have you considered using gestures instead of buttons?

Comment: I wouldn't put them in a row in the tableview, because if the tableview has lots of cells , the user will have to scroll up to see the buttons.

Comment: I thought about gestures, but couldn't find any easy enough for my purpose. For the intended use case a playlists normally consists of 10 to 20 items. Instead of using a start button I thought about tapping an item starts the playback, but this way, if I wanted to edit a song, I'd have to delete it.